# Magento - dev server - url doesn't work

Tags: url, magento, installation

I am attempting to set up Magento on my Dev Server, but I can't get the URL to work.

I have a copy of the live version, which I installed. I then updated the `config.xml` file, emptied the cache folder (`var/cache`) and updated `core_config_data` with the new URL, but for some reason I am still getting redirected to the live URL rather than the Dev URL which I just configured.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If non of the other answers here, about ensuring ALL the values are set correctly in the database, are correct, it might be that the var/cache directory wasn't writable. In which case you would need to clear your cache in the system temp directory (/tmp/magento/ on most *nix based systems).

As an alternative, check your .htaccess file and ensure your live domain isn't referred to at all (RedirectRules, Redirect etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the database, look for `core_config_data` table. You need to change the value of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to your dev server url.

You may need to clear the cache on `./var/cache`

Answer (score 0):

In Your Development Server Database has the Live Server Url.

Just find and replace the Live server Url with Development Server Url in Dev server Database.

**Example:**

**Live Server :**

```
http://live-server.com
```

**Development server :**

```
http://dev-server.com
```

You Just Find the  `http://live-server.com` in Development server Database And replace with `http://dev-server.com`.

It would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing the session folder?

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpmyadmin, execute this query and correct found values.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE  "%url%") AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. :) I found my own issue...

Apparently I had a copy of the live file in `app/etc/local.xml` as `backup_local.xml`

However, the application loads **all** files which have the `.xml` extension - so it was loading the `backup_local.xml` file as well... Oops!

I hope this catch helps other users with a similar issue!